# IE 10 flex box and text truncate

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

```css
.wrapper {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.right {

}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class="left">
    title title title title
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a DIV (`wrapper`) with 2 DIVs inside: `left` and `right`.

`wrapper`'s width is known. I want to truncate text in `left` DIV if it doesn't fit. Text in `right` should be always visible. I tried several techniques here, but the only one is working is based on flex box. Unfortunately it doesn't work on IE10. I used `-ms-` prefixes, without success.

Is there any way to make it work on IE10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this on IE10 myself, though since its `-ms-flex` defaults to `0 0 auto`, you will need to add `-ms-flex: 0 1 auto` to the `left`, so it is allowed to shrink.

And as the default on IE11 and the rest of the browsers is `0 1 auto`, they work as is.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xrt1wtdg/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;                     /*  IE10  */
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;                       /*  IE10  */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.right {

}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class="left">
    title title title title
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the same issue as in table solution: `123` text goes to right side if `wrapper` is wide. It's because of `flex: 1` in `left`

Comment: @user3452568 Updated my answer, and with that it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea without the use of flexbox but using `display:table`:

```css
.wrapper {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  display: table;
}

.left {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.left span {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.right {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
  <div class="left">
    <span>
    title title title title title title
   </span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx! it does the trick with ellipsis but when my `wrapper` is wider e.g. 200px, text `123` goes to the right side :( And I want to have it next to `left` DIV.

Comment: @user3452568 ah, it's because of the width 100% i applied to the first ... i will think about a trick